# My gulp.js CSS task isn't working correctly and I can't figure out why

Tags: sass, gulp, frontend, gulp-sass

I'm having an issue combining the CSS from the Foundation Sites NPM and my own SCSS. For some reason the generated CSS file includes all of the Foundation CSS but won't add anything from my SASS files.

Here is my CSS task (with variables):

```
var CSS_SOURCE = 'assets/src/scss';
var CSS_DEST = 'assets/dist/css';
var CSS_OUTPUT_FILE = 'main.css';


gulp.task('css', function() {
  gulp.src([
    'node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.css',
    CSS_SOURCE + 'main.scss'
  ])
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }}))
    .pipe(concat(CSS_OUTPUT_FILE))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(CSS_DEST + '/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(CSS_DEST + '/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }))
});
```

Here is my main.scss file:

```
@import "custom-settings";
@import "typography";
@import "header";
@import "navigation";
@import "buttons";
@import "main-content";
@import "footer";
```

Gulp isn't logging any errors. No matter what I put in my individual SASS files, none of it gets added to the bottom of the /dist/main.css file. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, I needed to include the path for the imports to work in the main.scss file. I also needed to add an extra forward slash in gulp.src. Here is the working task:

```
gulp.task('css', function() {
  gulp.src([
    'node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.css',
    CSS_SOURCE + '/main.scss'
  ])
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
    }}))
    .pipe(sass({
      includePaths: [
        CSS_SOURCE
      ]
    }))
    .pipe(concat(CSS_OUTPUT_FILE))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(CSS_DEST + '/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(cleanCSS())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(CSS_DEST + '/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream:true }))
});
```